cancelAll() and cancel() don't dismiss my notification Android
My notification just stays there and never disappears when I call cancelAll() / cancel() from the notification manager, also I have autoCancel set to true, can you help me ? thanks
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
String idCourse;
private String origine;
private String destination;

private double originLatitude;
private double originLongitude;

private double destLatitude;
private double destLongitude;
private String prix;
private String type;
private String distance;
private String numTelephoneClient;
private String motif_annulation;
private String numTelephoneConducteur;
private String dateCourse;
public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL";

NotificationChannel channel;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) { // channel for notifications

        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);

        String name = CHANNEL_ID;
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

        channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);

        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
   
    
    System.out.println("From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        System.out.println("From:2 " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        idCourse = remoteMessage.getData().get("idCourse");
        origine = remoteMessage.getData().get("origine");
        destination = remoteMessage.getData().get("destination");
        prix = remoteMessage.getData().get("prix");
        originLatitude = Double.parseDouble(remoteMessage.getData().get("OriginLatitude"));
        originLongitude = Double.parseDouble(remoteMessage.getData().get("OriginLongitude"));
        destLatitude = Double.parseDouble(remoteMessage.getData().get("destLatitude"));
        destLongitude = Double.parseDouble(remoteMessage.getData().get("destLongitude"));
        type = remoteMessage.getData().get("type");
        numTelephoneClient = remoteMessage.getData().get("numTelephoneClient");
        motif_annulation = remoteMessage.getData().get("Motif_annulation");
        numTelephoneConducteur = remoteMessage.getData().get("numTelephoneConducteur");
        dateCourse = remoteMessage.getData().get("dateCourse");
        distance = remoteMessage.getData().get("distance");
        System.out.println("remoteMessage.getData()type" +type);
        System.out.println("remoteMessage.getData().get(\"OriginLatitude\")  "+remoteMessage.getData().get("OriginLatitude"));
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        System.out.println("Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

FCM
// message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
System.out.println("From:3 " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
//  sendNotification(remoteMessage.getFrom(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);

    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    sendRegistrationToServer(token);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
}



private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
     int DELAY = 15000;
    System.out.println("From:4 ");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
        if (Objects.nonNull(type)&&type.equals("N")) {
            System.out.println("From:5 ");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AffectationCourseActivity.class);
            if(Objects.nonNull(idCourse)){
                intent.putExtra("id_course", Integer.parseInt(idCourse));
            }
            intent.putExtra("origine", origine);
            intent.putExtra("destination", destination);
            intent.putExtra("prix", prix);
            intent.putExtra("OriginLatitude", originLatitude);
            intent.putExtra("OriginLongitude", originLongitude);
            intent.putExtra("destLatitude", destLatitude);
            intent.putExtra("destLongitude", destLongitude);
            intent.putExtra("type", "N");
            intent.putExtra("numTelephoneClient", numTelephoneClient);
            intent.putExtra("distance",distance);
            System.out.println("distance  "+distance);

     
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AffectationCourseActivity.class);
            System.out.println("From:6 ");
            if(Objects.nonNull(idCourse)){
                intent.putExtra("id_course", Integer.parseInt(idCourse));
            }
            intent.putExtra("origine", origine);
            intent.putExtra("destination", destination);
            intent.putExtra("OriginLatitude", originLatitude);
            intent.putExtra("OriginLongitude", originLongitude);
            intent.putExtra("type", "O");
            intent.putExtra("numTelephoneClient", numTelephoneClient);
      
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        }

    System.out.println("From:7 ");

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

  
    Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sound);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL" )
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.saferide_logo)
            .setContentTitle( "Creation course" )
            .setSound(sound)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTimeoutAfter(10000)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentText( messageBody ) ;

    System.out.println("From:77 ");
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context. NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
   if (android.os.Build.VERSION. SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES. O ) {
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes. CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION )
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes. USAGE_ALARM )
                .build() ;
        System.out.println("From:778 ");
        channel.enableLights( true ) ;
        channel.setLightColor(Color. RED ) ;
        channel.enableVibration( true ) ;
        channel.setVibrationPattern( new long []{ 100 , 200 , 300 , 400 , 500 , 400 , 300 , 200 , 400 }) ;
        channel.setSound(sound , audioAttributes) ;
        mBuilder.setChannelId("NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL") ;
        assert mNotificationManager != null;
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel) ;

        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        System.out.println("From:7788 ");
        assert mNotificationManager != null;
        mNotificationManager.notify( 2 ,
                notification) ;

       new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed (() -> {  
           notificationManager.cancelAll();
       
       }, 15000);

       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               notificationManager.cancelAll();
             
           }
       }, 15000);
    }
    else {

        Uri defaultSoundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sound);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.saferide_logo)
                        .setContentTitle("Creation course")
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setTimeoutAfter(10000)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                        .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent,true)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notification);

       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               notificationManager.cancel(0);
          
               notificationManager.cancelAll();
           
           }
       }, 15000);
    }

}

}
